# Ubuntu bootable drive- Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e ; MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list

Tags: boot, uefi

I made a bootable drive with Etcher on my Mac. I followed the instructions to erase and properly partition the USB flash drive. It is MS-DOS FAT 32 with a GUID partition scheme.

When I try to boot or check for errors I get a black screen as shown below with the errors listed in the title:

```
[   8.608429] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[   8.608453] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
[   8.626775] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
```

In that order. I have tried on two different USB drives so far. I made sure to eject the disk when prompted to initialize or eject after Etcher finished installing and validating the ISO. The ISO was downloaded from Ubuntu's page. It is 18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso 
I am using a late 2011 Macbook Pro Laptop. Is the ISO possibly the wrong format for my device?

Also when I select the option to boot on restart I get two EFI boot options, both of which do the same thing.

Comment: [Setparams Ubuntu Boot Edit Screen][1]!


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWaXY.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148387/modsign-couldnt-get-uefi-db-list-couldnt-get-size-0x800000000000000e)

Comment: @karel I don’t know. I can no longer reproduce the same environment as the device has stopped working and after troubleshooting and discussion with Apple they deemed it to be unfixable and unable to be sent in for repair due to year of creation.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with:

AMD Athlon 200GE Dual-core 
MSI B450I Gaming Plus AC

I followed this guide to install Elementary OS, should be the same with Ubuntu

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10000/elementary-os-wont-boot-past-live-cd-screen

Once installed I used the same nomodeset to boot into Elementary OS

Once booted in I updated the kernel to 4.19 using this guide

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/10/linux-kernel-4-19-released-install-ubuntu/

I had no more issues after that

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out shortly and update from there.

Comment: I tried it out and I got the same error. I think something may be incorrect with the ISO or drive type I am using to boot.

This is what I got.    


[Setparams Ubuntu Boot Edit Screen][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWaXY.jpg .

Answer (score 2):

Use a live usb stick of the same ubuntu version. 
Open terminal.

```
sudo -i
fsck /dev/sdaX
```

Replace 'X' with your root disk name,and then with all other drives present.
You can check it with `fdisk -l`.
Reboot. Remove live usb.
It should work now.