# Ubuntu installer, Couldn't get size:0x800000000000000e

Tags: system-installation, uefi, 19.04

So I just installed Ubuntu 19.04 and it worked fine, but I realised it made a typo on the computer name, I am new to linux as it is and I thought it's a fresh install anyway just reinstall it than figure out how to change it. But now whenever I go to the same bootable and try to install ubuntu it says

```
Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
```

And then the screen goes all strange and glitched:
[Picture of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejV1e.jpg)

I have disabled secure boot and all other steps I could find but I don't understand how it can go from working normally to being broken just be a reinstall.

I am installing Ubuntu 19.04 on a 240gb SSD, in the same system is a Windows install running on a raid SSD array if that makes any difference. And I am using a Asus z390-f motherboard. Any help would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu bootable drive- Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e ; MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095766/ubuntu-bootable-drive-couldnt-get-size-0x800000000000000e-modsign-couldnt)

Comment: I had seen that thread but when looking around I was seeing different things with secure boot, and as I am using a different motherboard and not installing on a partition with the glitched screen effect I thought I was different. I can't get the steps to work on that thread either.

Comment: It is best to state that in the question to avoid close voting. Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed the issue, it was the GPU that was causing the problem not too sure why it worked before but anyway if anyone else is having the issue I fixed it by:

1. Installing Ubuntu 19.04 using using the safe graphics option
2. Once that has installed reboot the computer at it will have the broken screen that freezes
3. Turn off your computer and reboot using the motherboard graphics (Unplug the Display port/HDMI cable from your graphics card and put it into your motherboard)
4. You should then be able to boot into the Ubuntu 19.04 OS, from there go to software updater and update your GPU drivers by going to additional drivers and changing it to the priority and tested drivers and click apply (For a more detailed tutorial on how to update graphics drivers [look here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/)
5. Power down the system and put your HDMI/Display Port cable back into your GPU and you should be all set

Answer (score 0):

I would also say to always "try" before you install.  I found I had the same issue running the OS from USB.

As an alternative solution I downloaded Pop-OS with the Nividia drivers (my graphics card) and it worked.  I couldn't find an ubuntu download with the drivers and installing Pop-OS was easier than doing the steps above.