# Can't install Ubuntu on new windows machine

Tags: system-installation

Ubuntu won't install. Have a new computer with Win 10. Have formatted the drive to add a partition for Ubuntu 18.04. Used Rufus to get Ubuntu onto a USB Stick. With USB Stick in place, I reboot and get the message: "Couldn't get size: 0x8000...". Anybody have a fix for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu bootable drive- Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e ; MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095766/ubuntu-bootable-drive-couldnt-get-size-0x800000000000000e-modsign-couldnt) and [Live USB for installation does not boot, black error screen followed by visual artifacts on a purple screen](https://askubuntu.com/q/1077486/)

Answer (score 0):

Does it boot?

According to https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2424000&page=2 you can safely ignore the message but it sounds to me like maybe you have the wrong kernel version?