# Getting errors while trying to install ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, uefi

When I put my DVD-ROM and select the option to install Ubuntu, a black screen appears that says:

```
Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000e
MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000e
```

All the answers that I found on the internet were talking about disabling Secure Boot, but my motherboard doesn't support UEFI, so I don't have this option. What should I do?

Comment: UEFI replaced BIOS some years ago, how old is your machine? When you turn it on and press Shift or maybe F2 (depends on hardware) do you get a configuration menu of some kind?

Comment: Mine is Lenovo G580 and when I press F2 it gets me to Setup Utility with the above categories listed:Information,Configuration,Security,Boot and Exit

Comment: So F2 into the setup utility & go through the options and disable anything resembling secure boot or fast boot, don't touch anthing else. Check that the installer you burned to DVD was **ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso** and try again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148387/modsign-couldnt-get-uefi-db-list-couldnt-get-size-0x800000000000000e) and [Ubuntu bootable drive- Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e ; MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list](https://askubuntu.com/q/1095766/)